# How to add JasperReports page preview elements

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I hope you can help me. Google wasn't able to help me yet. Well, actually I don't even know what to search for exactly.

I try to create a file (in this case .xls) via JasperReports and Java. The file itself is filled and has the same format as the .jasper file. My problem is now to divide the design into the table view and the printed version. When watching the sheet, I only want to see the data and the header similar to a CSV file.

```
+--------+----------------------+-------+--------+
| Amount | Name                 | each  | total  |
+--------+----------------------+-------+--------+
| 2      | iPhone 5s            | $ 699 | $ 1398 |
| 1      | Samsung Galaxy S4    | $ 499 | $ 499  |
| 4      | USB Connection cable | $ 5   | $ 20   |
+--------+----------------------+-------+--------+
```

When printing (or even when opening the page preview) I want to add the page number and some header information like the report name or stuff (I want to define them on my own).

```
Date: 11/25/2013                                  reference Number: 0X6584A8BFC

                                DELIVERY

             +--------+----------------------+-------+--------+
             | Amount | Name                 | each  | total  |
             +--------+----------------------+-------+--------+
             | 2      | iPhone 5s            | $ 699 | $ 1398 |
             | 1      | Samsung Galaxy S4    | $ 499 | $ 499  |
             | 4      | USB Connection cable | $ 5   | $ 20   |
             +--------+----------------------+-------+--------+

                               PAGE 1/2
```

How can I tell jasper to add those information? Could you give me some Keywords? Is it possible anyway?

Thanks for your help

Zota

-- edit

My task is to find a more stable way of creating documents. Currently we're using an Open Office server converting the data to ods, odt etc. and then again to pdf xls etc. The documents has to look exactly the same as they were before. I've searched a bit on how it was solved before and found the data inside the header and footer area of the document.

In LibreOffice Calc --> open Document --> Edit --> Headers & Footers ...

There you can add data not visible on the sheet but on the printed document. I know, in Jasper you therefore have bands but when adding data to the page band, it will still be printed inside the sheet. How can I tell jasper to put those information into the header section and NOT inside the sheet?

Comment: I created the design (.jrxml) via iReport and compiled it using the jasperreports-maven-plugin. I was able to create (and fill) each design themselves. I haven't tried much yet but mostly because I don't know what to search for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add data to the header/footer section of my (your) files, you can use

```
net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.sheet.footer.center
net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.sheet.footer.left
net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.sheet.footer.right
net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.sheet.header.center
net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.sheet.header.left
net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.sheet.header.right
```

as property keys. The available properties are listed [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html). With those properties, I was able to add data to the document shown on the printed version but not when viewing the sheet.

Thanks to everyone who tried to help =)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add more details to the answer above:
If you want to assign dynamic content to these parameters, just use the following from your java code:

```
jasperPrint.getPropertiesMap().setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.sheet.footer.left", "the dynamic text");
```

Referred from here : http://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-library/issues/5193

It took too long for me to find that out. Might be helpful to others.